# Yii 2 после переноса на сервер 404 ошибка

Tags: yii2

Тестировал на OpenServer под win. После копирования на линукс сервер получаю 404 ошибку. 
Контроллер прост до боли

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

одуреть. сервер не понимал регистр. то есть если папка с view называется viewFolder то если обратиться к viewfolder/ он говорил что нет такого файла. насколько понимаю это на сервере нужно править

Comment: хм , то что в линуксе различается регистр файлов, для вас новость? Почему вы тогда переходите на линукс?

Comment: "насколько понимаю это на сервере нужно править" - можно только пожелать удачи в этом начинании